# Python: parallelizing operations on a big array iteratively

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize operations on a big array. I summarized my approach in the code snippet below. Since the operations on the big array are costly, of the 100 processes, I want to parallelize 4 (i.e. n_cpus) at each iteration. After an iteration is finished, some garbage collection will be done and the next iteration should start. The main loop does the first iteration and terminates. I will be glad if some parallel processing expert can point out how I can correct my code to achieve the desired task.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def train_model(model, big_array, i):
    model = do_operations_on(big_array)

# edit: this part is within a class
n_processes = 100
n_cpus = 4
models = [None for _ in range(n_processes)]
n_iterations = n_processes / n_cpus
for it in range(n_iterations):
    procs = [Process(target=train_model, \
        args=(models[it*n_cpus+i], big_array, i)) for i in range(n_cpus)]

    for p in procs: p.start()
    for p in procs: p.join()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code. It is the most simple way to use multiple processes and it is correct. However, communication between processes should be done with queues instead of writing to global variables, like 'models' in your case.
Do you have different operations, e. g. different train models, that should be applied to your array?

Comment: You are right. I checked it out and the above snippet works. However, in my original application, train_model is outside whereas rest of the code is within a class.  Then, the main loop does the first iteration and terminates. I will update if I have made a silly mistake or there is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea seems basically OK, except for a few problems:

- As RaJa pointed out, you should probably pass stuff using queues instead of using shared state
- I think your use of `multiprocessing.Process` is unnecessarily low level here; you should be using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), which would also be more efficient, as you can just reuse the processes (instead of keeping up setting them up and tearing them down).
- Your code has some mixup as your `train_model` ignores `model` and `i`, and just overwrites model.

So, in the following code, I assume you have something like

```
def train_model(specs, big_array):
    return ...
```

that takes some `spec` specifics and data, and returns a model built for these specifics.

I also assume in the following you have some array `specifics` containing all the specifics you want to try (and also that it is divisible in the number of cpus, which is not that difficult to get rid of).

Finally, I assume the point is to build a list `models` of all the models.

Your code becomes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

n_cpus = 4
n_iterations = len(specifics) / n_cpus
models = []
p = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cpus)
for it in range(n_iterations):
    cur_specs = specifics[it * n_cpus: (it + 1) * n_cpu]
    cur_models = p.map(lambda specs: train_model(specs, big_array), cur_specs)
    models.extend(cur_models)
    # Cleanup here
```

Comment: Could you explain what `specifics[it * n_cpus: (it + 1) * n_cpu]` means or does?

Comment: @martineau Edited above so that the sub-expressions have more descriptive names. Does this address your comment? Also, in the course of doing so, found a typo (corrected). Thanks.

Comment: Well, not so much...I had hoped you would explain that you were taking a slice of the values in `specifics` array for each iteration, which might compensate for the somewhat vague description of its contents given earlier in the answer.

Comment: @AmiTavory Many thanks for the detailed answer and suggestions. With queues, I keep getting "can't  pickle" or "object is not callable" type of errors. I will invest some more time to see if I can get everything to work though.

Comment: The least troublesome solution when working with classes seems to be using joblib (still based on multiprocessing Pool). Here is a one-liner that works (a bit slow though).  for it in range(n_iters): models.extend( Parallel(n_jobs=n_cpus)(delayed(train_model)(specs, big_array) for i in range(n_cpus)) )

Comment: :-) Was about to write about joblib. It's a good option. I must say that I eventually dropped it in favor of a version of multiprocessing I hacked which internally uses [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) instead of pickle.